# Parsing or using variables from a called script?

Tags: javascript

I have an AJAX function which loads content from a file and displays in the file that called it.

But the script that was called I want to loop an array which is actually set in the script that called it... this is main script that calls the file:

```
function call_file(file, div_id) {
    var xmlhttp;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById(div_id).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", file, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
var global = new Array();
global[0] = 1;
global[1] = 2;
call_script('html.html', 'main');
```

html.html is the file that is called which has this:

```
<script>
    i = 0;
    for(var id in global) {
        alert(i + ' = ' + id);
        i++;
    }
</script>
```

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to extract the script and eval it yourself. For example:

```
//....
document.getElementById(div_id).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
var str = xmlhttp.responseText;
var reg = /<script>([^>]*)<\/script>/img;
while(reg.test(str))eval(RegExp.$1);
//...
```

Comment: isn't eval a very bad idea in general ?

Comment: It's not bad in this case because you are exactly loading javascript code as strings, eval is the only way. Of course it would be better if you can avoid it by dynamically insert a script tag in header, but the html.html should be pure javascript without any tags.

Comment: Shouldn't a file that only contains javascript have the extension .js and be dynamically added to the page with a script tag, a type, and a src ? Like google or facebook apis files ?